# Несколько форм с файлами ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Что не так? почему не отправляется? пробовал before send подсвечивать незаполненные поля красным, в итоге просто сообщение об успешной отправке (на сайте, а здесь с тем же кодом ошибка), даже если ничего не заполнено

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("form.vacancies-form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    var formContent = $(this).find('.form-content');
    var formTitle = $(this).children('.title');
    var successMsg = $(this).children('.success-msg');
    var successName = $(this).find('.success-msg .name');

    $(this).addClass('vacancies-form--success');
    formContent.hide();
    formTitle.hide();
    successMsg.show();
    successName.text(formData.get('name'));

    $.ajax({
      url: 'sender.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      success: function success(data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert('send success');
      },
      error: function error(data) {
        console.log('error sending');
        formContent.show();
        formTitle.show();
        successName.text();
        successMsg.hide();
        $(this).removeClass('vacancies-form--success');
      },
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="job-form vacancies-form" id="data" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
   <input type="hidden" name="checked_form" value="Начинающий стоматолог-терапевт">
   <div class="title">
      <p>Запишитесь на собеседование</p>
   </div>
   <div class="success-msg">
      <p class="name"></p>
      <p class="text">Ваша заявка успешно отправлена!</p>
      <p class="text">Вскоре мы свяжемся с Вами</p>
   </div>
   <div class="form-content">
      <div class="input-wrap"><span class="input-title">Имя</span>
         <input class="form-input" type="text" placeholder="" name="name">
      </div>
      <div class="input-wrap"><span class="input-title">Номер телефона</span>
         <input class="form-input phone" type="text" placeholder="" name="phone">
      </div>
      <label class="file-label">
      <input class="file-upload" type="file" placeholder="Прикрепить резюме" name="file[]" value="1" size="40" multiple=""><span>Прикрепить резюме</span>
      </label>
      <div class="note">
         <p class="text">Отправляя это сообщение, вы соглашаетесь с </p>
         <a class="link" href="https://klinikajemchujnaya.ru/politika-obrabotki-personalnykh-dannykh" target="_blank">политикой конфиденциальности</a>
      </div>
      <button class="btn-md btn btn--accent" type="submit"><span class="btn__text">Отправить</span></button>
   </div>
</form>

<form class="job-form vacancies-form" id="data" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
   <input type="hidden" name="checked_form" value="Опытный  стоматолог-ортопед">
   <div class="title">
      <p>Запишитесь на собеседование</p>
   </div>
   <div class="success-msg">
      <p class="name"></p>
      <p class="text">Ваша заявка успешно отправлена!</p>
      <p class="text">Вскоре мы свяжемся с Вами</p>
   </div>
   <div class="form-content">
      <div class="input-wrap"><span class="input-title">Имя</span>
         <input class="form-input" type="text" placeholder="" name="name">
      </div>
      <div class="input-wrap"><span class="input-title">Номер телефона</span>
         <input class="form-input phone" type="text" placeholder="" name="phone">
      </div>
      <label class="file-label">
      <input class="file-upload" type="file" placeholder="Прикрепить резюме" name="file[]" value="1" size="40" multiple=""><span>Прикрепить резюме</span>
      </label>
      <div class="note">
         <p class="text">Отправляя это сообщение, вы соглашаетесь с </p>
         <a class="link" href="https://klinikajemchujnaya.ru/politika-obrabotki-personalnykh-dannykh" target="_blank">политикой конфиденциальности</a>
      </div>
      <button class="btn-md btn btn--accent" type="submit"><span class="btn__text">Отправить</span></button>
   </div>
</form>

<form class="job-form vacancies-form" id="data" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
   <input type="hidden" name="checked_form" value="Детский стоматолог">
   <div class="title">
      <p>Запишитесь на собеседование</p>
   </div>
   <div class="success-msg">
      <p class="name"></p>
      <p class="text">Ваша заявка успешно отправлена!</p>
      <p class="text">Вскоре мы свяжемся с Вами</p>
   </div>
   <div class="form-content">
      <div class="input-wrap"><span class="input-title">Имя</span>
         <input class="form-input" type="text" placeholder="" name="name">
      </div>
      <div class="input-wrap"><span class="input-title">Номер телефона</span>
         <input class="form-input phone" type="text" placeholder="" name="phone">
      </div>
      <label class="file-label">
      <input class="file-upload" type="file" placeholder="Прикрепить резюме" name="file[]" value="1" size="40" multiple=""><span>Прикрепить резюме</span>
      </label>
      <div class="note">
         <p class="text">Отправляя это сообщение, вы соглашаетесь с </p>
         <a class="link" href="https://klinikajemchujnaya.ru/politika-obrabotki-personalnykh-dannykh" target="_blank">политикой конфиденциальности</a>
      </div>
      <button class="btn-md btn btn--accent" type="submit"><span class="btn__text">Отправить</span></button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: не работаю с jquery и в точности не знаю как работает $(селектор) - возвращает ли он коллекцию дом-элементов или первый подошедший. но похоже дело в том, что у вас несколько форм с одинаковым id. либо вызов $ возвращает коллекцию а обработчик надо навешивать на дом-элемент, либо просто дом выдает ошибку поп поводу неуникальных id и по данному селектору ничего не ищется. это мое предположение - проверять лень

Comment: в любом случае одинаковые id это не дело - предлагаю заменить на дата-атрибуты ну или хотя бы классы

Comment: Отличный совет. Теперь обратился по классу, но всё равно проблема осталась

Comment: @StepanIvanov , уберите в своём проекте  `send.php` - будет и у вас ошибка. Если существует даже пустой файл обработчика, доступный по `url:` - ajax-запрос завершится успешно. Обязательные к заполнению поля нужно отмечать атрибутом `required`